Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE" while doing following
Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXECUTE"

while doing following
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WELCOME(SURNAME IN VARCHAR2,KAKSHA IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('SURNAME IS' ||SURNAME|| 'KAKSHA IS'||KAKSHA);
END;

EXECUTE WELCOME('GHAGARE',10);

my expected output is SURANAME IS GHAGARE KAKSHA IS 10

This is just a typo - after the END; you are missing a / on a blank line.

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; 
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WELCOME(SURNAME IN VARCHAR2,KAKSHA IN VARCHAR2) IS BEGIN dbms_output.put_line('SURNAME IS' ||SURNAME|| 'KAKSHA IS '||KAKSHA); END;
/

EXECUTE WELCOME('GHAGARE',10);

Missing a / after the proc definition
